# Navigator pass value of selected radio or text to next page in flutter

Tags: flutter, radio-button, navigator

I want to show the radio result in the next page, but I don't know how to pass the data of radio or the words in the text field to the next page.

What I want is that if I choose Living Room, then the next page will show 'Location is Living Room'. If I choose others and also type 'game room' in the last option, then the next page will show 'Location is game room'.

How to do this with Navigator and radio?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Select A Location',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (context) => SelectALocation(),
        '/nextpage': (context) => NextPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class SelectALocation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectALocationState createState() => _SelectALocationState();
}

class _SelectALocationState extends State<SelectALocation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Select a location'),
          SelectLocationWidget(),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Next'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/nextpage', arguments: 'Location');
            },
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

enum Location {livingRoom, bedroom, kitchen, others }

class SelectLocationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SelectLocationWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectLocationWidgetState createState() => _SelectLocationWidgetState();
}

class _SelectLocationWidgetState extends State<SelectLocationWidget> {
  Location _location = Location.livingRoom;
  final TextEditingController _locationOthersController =
      new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Living Room'),
          value: Location.livingRoom,
          groupValue: _location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              _location = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Bedroom'),
          value: Location.bedroom,
          groupValue: _location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              _location = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Kitchen'),
          value: Location.kitchen,
          groupValue: _location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              _location = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: TextField(
            controller: _locationOthersController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Others',
            ),
          ),
          value: Location.others,
          groupValue: _location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              _location = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text('Location is $Location'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code, like changing the `SelectLocationWidget` from a `class` to a `widget`. The code below should work the way you want it, which includes what you type when you choose others:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Select A Location',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (context) => SelectALocation(),
        '/nextpage': (context) => NextPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

enum Location {livingRoom, bedroom, kitchen, others }

class SelectALocation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectALocationState createState() => _SelectALocationState();
}

class _SelectALocationState extends State<SelectALocation> {
  Location location = Location.livingRoom;
  String actualLocation = 'Living Room';
  final TextEditingController locationOthersController = new TextEditingController();

  Widget selectLocationWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Living Room'),
          value: Location.livingRoom,
          groupValue: location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              location = value;
              actualLocation = 'Living Room';
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Bedroom'),
          value: Location.bedroom,
          groupValue: location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              location = value;
              actualLocation = 'Bedroom';
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Kitchen'),
          value: Location.kitchen,
          groupValue: location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              location = value;
              actualLocation = 'Kitchen';
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: TextField(
            controller: locationOthersController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Others',
            ),
          ),
          value: Location.others,
          groupValue: location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              location = value;
              actualLocation = locationOthersController.text;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Select a location'),
            selectLocationWidget(),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Next'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context, 
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => NextPage(
                      locationText: actualLocation,
                    ),
                  )
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String locationText;
  NextPage({@required this.locationText});

  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('Location is ${widget.locationText}')
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste following code.

I moved your `RaisedButton` widget to the end of the Column in `SelectLocationWidget`. Because you are keeping the information of the selected location in `SelectLocationWidget`. Then I add a parameter for the `NextPage` to pass location. You might want to implement another function to print your `Location`. I used default `describeEnum` function to do that. But it prints Livig Room as livingRoom, so you might wanna fix it.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Select A Location',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (context) => SelectALocation(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class SelectALocation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectALocationState createState() => _SelectALocationState();
}

class _SelectALocationState extends State<SelectALocation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Select a location'),
          SelectLocationWidget(),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

enum Location {livingRoom, bedroom, kitchen, others }

class SelectLocationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SelectLocationWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectLocationWidgetState createState() => _SelectLocationWidgetState();
}

class _SelectLocationWidgetState extends State<SelectLocationWidget> {
  Location _location = Location.livingRoom;
  final TextEditingController _locationOthersController =
      new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Living Room'),
          value: Location.livingRoom,
          groupValue: _location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              _location = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Bedroom'),
          value: Location.bedroom,
          groupValue: _location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              _location = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: const Text('Kitchen'),
          value: Location.kitchen,
          groupValue: _location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              _location = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<Location>(
          title: TextField(
            controller: _locationOthersController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Others',
            ),
          ),
          value: Location.others,
          groupValue: _location,
          onChanged: (Location value) {
            setState(() {
              _location = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Next'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context, 
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NextPage(location: _location),
                ),
              );
            },
          )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Location location;

  NextPage({@required this.location});

  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text('Location is ${describeEnum(widget.location)}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```